# Using Matlab C++ compiler to convert C++ code into Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, compiler-errors, mex

I am trying to use the MinGW-w64 Compiler in Matlab. I have it installed and Matlab recognizes the compiler. My question is 2-fold:

1) I cannot get it to compile all the .c code into a header. I typed

```
 mex -output HTKToolsFolder *.c
 Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'.
```

And got

```
Error using mex
C:\Users\username\Documents\MATLAB\MatlabHTK\htk\HTKTools\HBuild.c:39:46:    fatal error: HShell.h: No such
file or directory
 #include "HShell.h" /* HMM ToolKit Modules */
                                          ^
compilation terminated.
```

I'm not sure what the .h extension is. That file is located in another folder but if I tell Matlab to compile .h files it doesn't recognize the file extension

```
mex -output hfilescompiled *.h
Error using mex
Unknown file extension '.h'.
```

If it helps, HShell.h is called by some of the .c files

The second question is, once question #1 is answered, can I apply this to a directory with many folders of C++ code? Or do I have to use the mex command for every single folder?

I've watched the Matlab tutorial: https://www.mathworks.com/solutions/matlab-and-c.html and I've also read the Matlab help files for mex and loadlibrary.

Any advice is greatly appreciated as this is the first time I've mixed C++ and Matlab. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You want to do this:

```
mex HBuild.c -IC:\Path\To\H\Files
```

where `C:\Path\To\H\Files` is whatever the directory is that contains `HShell.h`.

This will create a MEX-file called `HBuild` (assuming that `HBuild.c` contains a `mexFunction` function, and no other dependencies exist).

If you do `mex *.c`, then all C source files in that directory will be combined into a single MEX-file. I doubt that this is what you want. You need to call `mex` for each of the MEX-files you want to build. Each MEX-file will become a function available within MATLAB.